# Fortran two dimensional array issue

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, subroutine

I am trying to get value from a two dimensional array, but value I have at index is not what I am getting. Here is program:

```
 subroutine stlstp(y,n,np,ns,nt,nl,isdeg,itdeg,ildeg,nsjump,ntjump,nljump,ni,userw,rw,season,trend,work)

!     implicit none
! Arg
      integer n,np,ns,nt,nl,isdeg,itdeg,ildeg,nsjump,ntjump,nljump,ni
      logical userw
      double precision y(n),rw(n),season(n),trend(n),work(20,5)
! Var
      integer i,j



     do 80 j = 1,1
         do 1 i = 1,n
              work(i,1) = y(i)-trend(i)
 1       continue
         call stlss(y,n,np,ns,isdeg,nsjump,userw,rw,season)

         PRINT *, 'WORK 1,2 ....',work(1,2)
         PRINT *, 'WORK ....',work
         call stlfts(work(1,2),n+2*np,np,work(1,3),work(1,1))
```

`PRINT *, 'WORK...',work` printing [image]

Based on this output, shouldn't `PRINT *, 'Work1,2....'` return `193.0000`? but I am getting `0.000000` as output. Can someone please help with this? what am I missing?

Comment: @casey: Updated question with code. Work array is 20,5 shape. I hope now it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran uses column-major ordering for arrays, so for a shape of (20,5), the element (1,2) is the 21st element of the array.  Confusing this, the `print *,` will print the element in rows.  The element you have circled is (2,1).  Element (1,2) is the `0.000` located in the first column of row 5 of your output image.

Comment: ah! my stupid mistake. I read about column majoring, but didn't realize in action. Thanks!